# Unable to login to site even though I am administrator of the site collection

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, security, central-administration

I created one site collection and gave the site collection administrator as my name. But when I navigate to that site and try to login that site it is giving me an error that Access Denied. For all site collections it is giving me that error. Whats wrong here. Can any one help me!!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The site collection might be locked.Open Central administration, Application Management, Site quotas and locks.
Sit Lock information
Make sure the site is not locked.

Comment: I checked that one, it is in unlocked state only.

Answer (score 0):

From Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage Web Application, click on the specific web application and check User Permission, User Policy and Permission Policy if everything is in order, specifically check user policy, i guess something is wrong there

Comment: I checked all. Every thing is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is that site referencing content from some other site where you do not have permission? You might want to check on that.

Comment: No way.. the site didn't contain any data. I just made changes regarding branding thats it. Not linked to any site

Comment: What were the changes related to branding? Were any custom css or js files referenced? Is the Master Page checked in?